# migrating django app to apache server: ImportError: No module named registration

Tags: python, apache, webfaction

Im have been having trouble migrating django project to apache server. I think that python cannot find django registration but it is installed in: /home/user/lib/python2.7/django_registration-2.0.4.dist-info. 
but i also have python2.7 in: /home/user/webapps/myproject/lib/python2.7. I tried moving django registration to the second path to no avail.

I need help pointing django registration to the python module search path. According to webfaction docs it says, "you must add $HOME/webapps/django_app/lib/python2.7 to the Python module search path"

Thanks for the help before i start ripping out my hair!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about django, but typically python looks in the PYTHONPATH environment variable.  It looks like you are on a Linux platform, so try adding something like this to your system `.bashrc` file (or appropriate shell config):

```
export PYTHONPATH="$HOME/webapps/django_app/lib/python2.7:$PYTHONPATH"
```

Alternately, if you can find where the PYTHONPATH is already being set, just add `$HOME/webapps/django_app/lib/python2.7` to it.

If you are not running the bash shell, you will need to set the environment variable in the appropriate way...both versions of python should reference the same PYTHONPATH variable, so that shouldn't matter.

Comment: thanks for the resonse. i found where PYTHONPATH was and added the path to it but didnt work. I commented out registration from installed apps in settings and now i get: ImportError: No module named registration.backends.default.urls